# Why is the touch event not duplicated to my view?

Tags: java, android, events, touch, listeners

I am using the following `item.xml` layout for my list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:text="@string/title_placeholder"
            style="@style/title" />

        <com.myapp.android.view.MyView
            android:layout_width="11dp"
            android:layout_height="11dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/title"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using `duplicateParentState` in two places, my custom view `MyView` and the wrapping `RelativeLayout`. Still, I do not receive any touch events inside my view on which I registered an on touch listener, when I touch one of the list view's item.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

can you post your onTouch code?

**from android documentation:**

> onTouch() - This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener
>   consumes this event. The important thing is that this event can have
>   multiple actions that follow each other. So, if you return false when
>   the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not
>   consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions
>   from this event. Thus, you will not be called for any other actions
>   within the event, such as a finger gesture, or the eventual up action
>   event

Comment: Mine just returns true so I get the follow up events, too.

Comment: have you tried setting it to return false -"don't consume"

Comment: not really no, plus I am missing the follow up events, now